# running the simplest Google Appengine code but the log said python25.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

I tried the simplest hello world app in Google AppEngine 
I already download and setup 
1) Python 2.7
2) Google Appengine launcher
create an app

app.yaml

```
application: first
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.php
```

the main.php

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world!';
```

I can't run the app or deploy it .
the log said :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 196, in <module>
  run_file(__file__, globals())
 File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 192, in run_file
 execfile(script_path, globals_)
 File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 44, in     <module>
  import mimetypes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 29, in <module> import urllib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>import socket
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
  import _socket
  ImportError: Module use of python25.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
   2013-12-20 00:26:34 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I reinstall the launcher but it didn't work .

Comment: Clearly a case of having Python 2.5 and 2.7. Can you hunt this python25.dll down and delete it ? that should solve your problem.

Comment: I double checked I have only Python 2.7 !

Answer (score 0):

Google app engine launcher didn't work for me.
To deploy i used following command in command prompt

```
python appcfg.py -A YOUR_PROJECT_ID update <path to your project>/app.yaml
```